# vertical-align: middle an <img> inside a div doesn't centers image

Tags: html, css

I have a div called product-large and there's an img as a child inside it. The structure looks as follows:

```
<div class="product-large">
         <img id="product-image" src="http://cf.shopious.com/images/store_logos/thumbnail/2159d3537713da6dd80c80b33c87bbc1ce2c2aac.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

The issue is that product-image is not centered, instead it sticks to the top. I've already used vertical-align: middle in the img css. Why is this?

You can see the full working site [here](http://dev.shopious.com/items/407/Estacia-Blouse) (inspect element on the large image)

Comment: I'm pretty bad with html but changing the display property to either absolute or table might fix this

Comment: @Accipheran I tried adding table-cell to product-large and it didn't work

Comment: That’s just not what `vertical-align` does. It’s a pretty common problem in CSS, and there are several different solutions depending on whether your image has a fixed size, whether CSS hacks are okay, what kind of browser compatibility you need, and how clean you want to keep your HTML…

Comment: @minitech so how do I solve this? I just wanted the image to be centered whether it's vertically or horizontally. The image size varies. CSS hacks are fine.

Comment: @adit: [Like this](http://codepen.io/minitech/pen/gzkAs), for example.

Comment: if you are open to css3 standards then using flex box layout will be pretty easy to center your image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Alternative method of centering**

1) Get the fixed height & width of the img and make position:relative for image and containing div 
2) Position the image at 50% top & 50% left (now top left corner is in the center) 
3) Apply a margin-left at negative half of the image width, and apply a margin-top at negative half of the img height

Example with a 200px cat image in a div called container:

```
.container {position:relative; width:600px; height:600px; background:red;}

.cat {position:relative; height:200px; width:200px; top:50%; left:50%; margin-top:-100px; margin-left:-100px;}
```

[JS FIDDLE LINK - http://jsfiddle.net/qhWLK/](http://jsfiddle.net/qhWLK/)

Edit: If image size varies this method can still be effective using jQuery to get the image size and apply the centering CSS on page load or document ready

Answer (score 0):

I think for vertical-align: middle, you need to have:

```
display: table-cell;
```

for the image

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
#main.product-detail .product-banner .product-large {
    display: table-cell;
    height: 437px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 437px;
}
```

this will solve your issue.

[jsFiddle Code](http://jsfiddle.net/JGF4m/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
div * {margin-top:auto; margin-bottom:auto;}
```

Try different width and height values on the img and different font size values on the span and you'll see they always remain in the middle of the container.